# Can I restrict Wireshark to only work with a specific interface

Tags: linux, networking, wireshark

I have a user who is running a package call mininet to simulate networks on the loopback interface. They will likely need to use Wireshark to debug these virtual networks they create. However we have a strict network policy and scanning packets on the main network is forbidden.

Is there any way I can configure wireshark and restrict it to only work with the loopback interface?

Thanks

Comment: This should be doable with a network and user namespace (assuming the OS is Linux), or aternatively with a fine-grained access control framework such as SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that while `wireshark` has an option for selecting the interface, it allows overriding it in the graphical interface.

As such, you can give `sudo` privilege for `tcpdump` and or `tshark` (text mode wireshark) to capture packets, and then read them later with `wireshark -r file`.

You have the option -i in `tcpdump` or `tshark` calling it from the command line; you can create a sudo authorization to `tshark` or `tcpdump` that allows your user to use it only with `-i interface`; the main loopback interface is usually `lo` in Linux

as in in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i lo -s0  -w - --
```

The "--" is shorthand from the ´getopt` argument parsing standard/call for stopping arguments for preventing the user from adding more interfaces than the one it is being allowed.

(I have not defined a capture file in purpose, so the user as to redirect the traffic for a file. Defining a capture file with a predictable name as a privileged user from a routine invoked from  lower privileged user has security implications)

I´d remember the user can see their `sudo` permissions with

```
sudo -l
```

because usually such commands have to be typed verbatim as they are in `sudo` for the `sudo` to work.

Comment: That's was a great idea, but unfortunately when you run the wireshark as root it appears to ignore the -i lo option and shows all of the devices on the machine.

Comment: @fyberoptik I was already afraid of that; better use the tcpdump then; nevertheless let me see what can be done about wireshark.

Comment: @fyberoptik short of compiling wireshark, only using tshark (text mode), or tcpdump, apparently.